# jQuery up/down image background with slide

Tags: jquery

I need to create a jquery control with the following description.

There will be an image background and a pane at bottom with text shown in figure 1.Clicking the up arrow will cause the pane to slide up completely covering the background with a transparent slide shown in figure 2. The transparent slide will show a brief text .

the images with the description of the functionality i need is on the following link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/f3b59305-0279-4601-bf91-819b146a3f53/jquery-updown-image-background?forum=scripting

Comment: And how's that going?

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: i don't know how do i do that,please suggest any solution

Comment: Then learn jQuery. Start here: http://jquery.com/ and move on towards reading/getting examples about sliders, for example: http://www.freshdesignweb.com/fullscreen-jquery-slider.html

Comment: Please suggest any solution which can do the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/videma/Q84d5/), all code jQuery you need is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count=1;
    $('#arrow').click(function(){
        count++;
        if (count%2 == 0){
            $('#cover').animate({'top':'0px'},500);
            $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');
            }else{
                $('#cover').animate({'top':'170px'},500);
                $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');
            };
        });
})
</script>
```

If you like it...remeber to vote